# Code for HTML 5 Animation

Tags: html

Can someone tell me the steps of using animation on this page:
http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/canvas-nebula.htm#disqus_thread

Answer (score 2):

Sure

As you can read [here](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/canvas-nebula.htm):

> This is a simple demonstration of a nebula effect using the HTML5 Canvas element. The effect is created by layering three images, derived from a larger single bitmap source, that fade in and out while increasing in scale. The non-repeating nature of the effect is created by having a larger bitmap than the view area and choosing a random texture offset.